# Angular 6 Get response headers with httpclient issue

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I'm using the code below to try to extract a value (ReturnStatus) from the response headers;

```
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
ReturnStatus: OK,SO304545
Server: Apache/2.4.29 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2m
```

The code;

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Account } from './model/account';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { map, filter, catchError, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

 createOrder(url) : Observable<any> {

  return this._http.get(url, {withCredentials: true, observe: 'response'})
  .pipe(
    map((resp: any) => {
      console.log("response", resp);
      return resp;

    }), catchError( error => {
      console.log("createOrder error",error );
      alert("Create Order Service returned an error. See server log for mote details");
    return throwError("createOrder: " + error)

    })
  );
}
```

However my console.log just give;

```
HttpResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: "OK", url: 
"http://localhost/cgi-bin/dug.cgi/wh?Page… 
plateLocation=C:%5Ctemp%5Corderimporttemplate.txt", ok: true, …}
```

I've looked on this site and others for the correct way to do this in Angular but to no avail?
Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Many thanks,

Mark.

Comment: what is your problem? where do you try to get response status and it fails?

Comment: it doesn't fail as such I'm just trying to find the correct way to get to the ReturnStatus line in the response header.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You need to observe the entire response as described below:

```
 createOrder(url) : Observable<HttpResponse<Object>>{

    return this.http.get<HttpResponse<Object>>(this.url, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(
         tap(resp => console.log('response', resp))
    );
}
```

Now inside resp you can access headers
An example

```
 createOrder(url) : Observable<HttpResponse<Object>>{

    return this.http.get<HttpResponse<Object>>(this.url, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(
         tap(resp => console.log('heaeder', resp.headers.get('ReturnStatus')))
    );
}
```

If you can't access your custom header as explained above it's because a small set of headers are exposed to javascript by default for security reasons.
Probably if you open developer tools and you inspect your response headers you should see the desired one.

**Who can choose which headers are exposed to javascript?**

Exposed headers are choosen by the web application (so your webservices, or your backend. Obviously you web application could be written using many languages and/or using many framework.

Depending on what you are using you can achieve this goal by different ways.

To give you an idea of what you should do I can post my Spring solution.
In class extending `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` you should add this two methods:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity
            // we don't need CSRF because our token is invulnerable
            .csrf().disable()
            .cors()
} 


@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addExposedHeader("Authorization, x-xsrf-token, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, " +
            "Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Custom-Filter-Header");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return new CorsFilter(source);
}
```

Note that I've disabled csrf because I'm using JWT.
Note that you should refine CorsFilter rules.

As you can see I have added `Custom-Filter-Header` into this line

```
config.addExposedHeader("Authorization, x-xsrf-token, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, " +
                "Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Custom-Filter-Header");
```

You can replace this `Custom-Filter-Header` with your `ReturnStatus`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for this. Unfortunately it looks like there maybe something else required also as this is a custom header? https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5237 details adding "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" to the API...

Comment: let me know if you are not using spring, if I can I should help you to solve your backend troubles :)

Comment: Very much appreciate the offer of help for this issue. For the moment we've coded around it by returning an XML response and parsing that instead

Comment: key thing inside config  - observe: "response" as 'body'. pipe tap is redundant

Comment: If anyone is using CORS and ASP.NET on the server, you have to explicitly expose the header value with the exposedHeaders parameter when you configuring CORS.

Comment: adding , {observe: 'response'} actually solved my issue.. thanks a lot!!!Was so frustrated with this error.

Comment: Also sometimes you want to change in node code in app.js put 
this.app.use(cors({
      exposedHeaders: ['Content-Length', 'token'],
    }));  Ref . https://truetocode.com/set-and-get-custom-response-header-values-using-angular-5-and-express-js-node-js/