# How to get header detail in angular 6 from spring boot api

Tags: spring-boot, header, angular6

I am calling spring boot rest api and setting cookie from sever side.
In response header how to get cookie info and angular 6. Below i have mention the header info

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin : http://localhost:4200
Content-Type    application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date Thu, 12 Jul 2018 10:48:49 GMT
Set-Cookie JSESSIONID=65F91470AD431D89BD9…05E2FA2B574; Path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie  useName=XXXXXXX
Transfer-Encoding   chunked
Vary    Origin
Vary    Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary    Access-Control-Request-Headers
```

Comment: Have you tried anything before posting here ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 Get response headers with httpclient issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968674/angular-6-get-response-headers-with-httpclient-issue)

Answer (score 0):

The headers are part of the [Response class](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/Response-class.html), so you should be able to see them in a handler like

```
http.get('/path/to/resource')
  .subscribe((res:Response) => {
    console.log(res.headers);
    // you can assign the value to any variable here
  });
```

Comment: ok..try to print response using JSON.stringify(res); and check whether header present or not

Comment: in response header detail is not coming but in firefox inspector header detail is avaialable

Comment: Try to get the details in your angular response...do some research

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript only some specific headers are exposed by default. It depends on server services. Look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968674/angular-6-get-response-headers-with-httpclient-issue/50969834#50969834) to see an example with SpringBoot