# Angular 6, multiple HttpHeaders can't be applied

Tags: angular, http-headers, angular6

Purpose:
To send the requests with 2 default headers: Content-Type and Authorization (Backend - Web API).
Conditions:
Angular version 6.0.1 and project that built with generator ngx-rocket.
Issue:
I add interceptor for Content-Type and it works.

```
 intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    request = request.clone({
      url: environment.serverUrl + request.url,
      setHeaders: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
      },
      body: this.convertToContentType(request.body)
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

When I was trying to add another header in the same function noone header was applied, and the same situation in every circumstance. It works ONLY with one header. I was trying to add another interceptor

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthorizationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const credentialsData = localStorage.getItem(token_key);
    if (credentialsData && JSON.parse(credentialsData)) {
      request = request.clone({
        // headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${JSON.parse(credentialsData).token}`)
        setHeaders: {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${JSON.parse(credentialsData).token}`
        }
      });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }

}
```

Here is my http.service.ts service code

```
import {Inject, Injectable, InjectionToken, Injector, Optional} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

import {ErrorHandlerInterceptor} from './error-handler.interceptor';
import {CacheInterceptor} from './cache.interceptor';
import {ApiPrefixInterceptor} from './api-prefix.interceptor';
import {AuthorizationInterceptor} from '@app/core/http/api-prefix.interceptor';

// HttpClient is declared in a re-exported module, so we have to extend the original module to make it work properly
// (see https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13897)
declare module '@angular/common/http/src/client' {

  // Augment HttpClient with the added configuration methods from HttpService, to allow in-place replacement of
  // HttpClient with HttpService using dependency injection
  export interface HttpClient {

    /**
     * Enables caching for this request.
     * @param {boolean} forceUpdate Forces request to be made and updates cache entry.
     * @return {HttpClient} The new instance.
     */
    cache(forceUpdate?: boolean): HttpClient;

    /**
     * Skips default error handler for this request.
     * @return {HttpClient} The new instance.
     */
    skipErrorHandler(): HttpClient;

    /**
     * Do not use API prefix for this request.
     * @return {HttpClient} The new instance.
     */
    disableApiPrefix(): HttpClient;

    disableAuthorizationHeader(): HttpClient;

  }

}

// From @angular/common/http/src/interceptor: allows to chain interceptors
class HttpInterceptorHandler implements HttpHandler {

  constructor(private next: HttpHandler, private interceptor: HttpInterceptor) {
  }

  handle(request: HttpRequest<any>): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.interceptor.intercept(request, this.next);
  }

}

/**
 * Allows to override default dynamic interceptors that can be disabled with the HttpService extension.
 * Except for very specific needs, you should better configure these interceptors directly in the constructor below
 * for better readability.
 *
 * For static interceptors that should always be enabled (like ApiPrefixInterceptor), use the standard
 * HTTP_INTERCEPTORS token.
 */
export const HTTP_DYNAMIC_INTERCEPTORS = new InjectionToken<HttpInterceptor>('HTTP_DYNAMIC_INTERCEPTORS');

/**
 * Extends HttpClient with per request configuration using dynamic interceptors.
 */
@Injectable()
export class HttpService extends HttpClient {

  constructor(private httpHandler: HttpHandler,
              private injector: Injector,
              @Optional() @Inject(HTTP_DYNAMIC_INTERCEPTORS) private interceptors: HttpInterceptor[] = []) {
    super(httpHandler);

    if (!this.interceptors) {
      // Configure default interceptors that can be disabled here
      this.interceptors = [
        this.injector.get(ApiPrefixInterceptor),
        // this.injector.get(AuthorizationInterceptor),
        this.injector.get(ErrorHandlerInterceptor)
      ];
    }
  }

  cache(forceUpdate?: boolean): HttpClient {
    const cacheInterceptor = this.injector.get(CacheInterceptor).configure({update: forceUpdate});
    return this.addInterceptor(cacheInterceptor);
  }

  skipErrorHandler(): HttpClient {
    return this.removeInterceptor(ErrorHandlerInterceptor);
  }

  disableApiPrefix(): HttpClient {
    return this.removeInterceptor(ApiPrefixInterceptor);
  }

  disableAuthorizationHeader(): HttpClient {
    return this.removeInterceptor(AuthorizationInterceptor);
  }

  // Override the original method to wire interceptors when triggering the request.
  request(method?: any, url?: any, options?: any): any {
    const handler = this.interceptors.reduceRight(
      (next, interceptor) => {
        return new HttpInterceptorHandler(next, interceptor);
      }, this.httpHandler
    );
    return new HttpClient(handler).request(method, url, options);
  }

  private removeInterceptor(interceptorType: Function): HttpService {
    return new HttpService(
      this.httpHandler,
      this.injector,
      this.interceptors.filter(i => !(i instanceof interceptorType))
    );
  }

  private addInterceptor(interceptor: HttpInterceptor): HttpService {
    return new HttpService(
      this.httpHandler,
      this.injector,
      this.interceptors.concat([interceptor])
    );
  }

}
```

I'm already sure that the issue is with headers, not with interceptors mechanism.

**UPDATE**

Here is the screenshot of request network tab, to ensure that headers are missing.
[Network screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gezr3.png)

Comment: have you exposed Authorization header into your backend?

Comment: look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968674/angular-6-get-response-headers-with-httpclient-issue/50969834#50969834

Comment: @firegloves I think if I send headers they will be visible in network tab. And i cannot see them. Am i wrong?

Comment: don't think: try :) i'm joking, i don't remember if you can see in the network tab, maybe not

Comment: and keep in mind that the browser can know if that particular header is valid because you have already made a data exchange with the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in Backend part, there was a settings restrictions of applyable headers.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code

```
let headers = request.headers
        .set('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        .set('Authorization', `Bearer ${JSON.parse(credentialsData).token}`);

@Injectable()
export class AuthorizationInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const credentialsData = localStorage.getItem(token_key);
    if (credentialsData && JSON.parse(credentialsData)) {
      request = request.clone({ headers });
    }
    return next.handle(request);
  }

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, yes