# Trouble accessing response headers with HTTP Client in Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm trying to access some custom headers in an HTTP response and have set my http client options in my request to observe the response, e.g:

```
  public createShift = () => {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/services/shift-events', {
      shiftEventType: 'START_SHIFT'
    }, { observe: 'response'});
  }
```

When this gets called, I see the header I am interested in ('Location') returned in the http response when viewing my browsers network activity, but I cannot access it in my code:

```
this.shiftEventsService.createShift().subscribe((response: HttpResponse<any>) => {
  console.log(response.headers.get('Location'));  //undefined
  const keys = response.headers.keys();
  keys.map(key =>
    console.log(`${key}: ${response.headers.get(key)}`) //no headers get logged out
  );
});
```

Headers in network tab are as follows:

[image]

I have even tried to log out any of the headers returned, and none are being found (e.g. the Access-Control-xxxx ones).

Logging out the value of my response in my subscription when calling createShift I see:

[image]

So zero headers returned.

I feel I am missing something obvious here, but when checking the [angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) and other guides out there I cannot see what it is.

Can someone help here?
Thanks

**UPDATE:**

I see the headers if I also try the same request in postman:

[image]

So this is nothing to do with the server not configured correctly from what I can tell.

**SOLVED**

This ended up being down to the fact the requests being made were actually triggering CORS preflight requests and the server implementation needed to add a `Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location` header in the response.

I'm now able to access the header using the code I have posted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 6 Get response headers with httpclient issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968674/angular-6-get-response-headers-with-httpclient-issue)

Comment: If you do a console.log(response.headers.keys()); are you seeing the Location header in the array that is returned?

Comment: @Lamp - no I dont see any values returned for the keys, just getting an empty array back.

Comment: @firegloves - yes its been asked before, but when I follow the steps in that answer I am not able to access any headers returned

Comment: i thinks as suggested by Lamp you should return a kay-value for your header, like 'myHeader': 'myValue'. You are returning an array

Comment: @firegloves - that wont make any difference since the length of response.headers.keys for me is zero

Comment: please use Network tab of developer tools of the browser and post Response Headers section

Comment: @firegloves - see my edited question with additional screenshots

Comment: it seems that backend service is not sending at all. with postman you can see your header?

Comment: @firegloves - its not the backend, see my update on my question with a postman screenshot. All headers are there!

Comment: i can't see other options. if the backend sends that header but you cannot see it into angular it should be a "connection configuration" problem. please post your backend code

Comment: maybe the problem resides into allowedheaders?

Comment: @firegloves - you helped me figure this out, see my latest update, it was server side and the fact an `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` entry was not being set