# Unable to get response header in http interceptor in angular 5

Tags: angular6

I am able to get the token from local storage after signin. After that I need to get the token from the header response as I need to store the new token again before the earlier one gets expired.

Below is my intercept file:

```
    import { environment } from './../../environments/environment';
    import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
    import {
        HttpRequest,
        HttpHandler,
        HttpEvent,
        HttpInterceptor,
        HttpErrorResponse,
        HttpResponse,
        HttpHeaderResponse,
        HttpClientModule
    } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
    import 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
    import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty';

    @Injectable()
    export class AppHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

        constructor(private router: Router) { }

        intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): 
        Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

            const token = this.getToken();  //first token after signin

            const JWT = `Bearer ${token}`;
            req = req.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    Authorization: JWT
                }
            });

            req = req.clone({ url: this.prepareUrl(req.url) });

            return next.handle(req)
                .do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                        console.log(event);  //here I am checking for a new 
                        token in event but unable to get that.
                    }
                })
                .catch((error, caught) => {
                    //intercept the response error and displace it to the console
                    console.log(error);

                    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                        if (error.status === 401) {
                            // redirect to the login route
                            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
                        }
                        else if (error.status === 0) {
                            // Show the error message
                            return Observable.empty<HttpEvent<any>>();
                        }
                    }

                    //return the error to the method that called it
                    return Observable.throw(error);


                }) as any;
        }


        private isAbsoluteUrl(url: string): boolean {
            const absoluteHttpPattern = /^http?:\/\//i;
            const absoluteHttpsPattern = /^https?:\/\//i;
            return absoluteHttpPattern.test(url) || absoluteHttpsPattern.test(url);
        }

        private prepareUrl(url: string): string {
            url = this.isAbsoluteUrl(url) ? url : environment.api + url;
            return url.replace(/([^:]\/)\/+/g, '$1');
        }

        getToken(): string {
            return localStorage.getItem('accessToken');
        }
    }
```

Below is the log response I am getting :

```
HttpResponsebody: Array[2]headers: HttpHeaderslazyInit: ()lazyUpdate: nullnormalizedNames: Map__proto__: Objectok: truestatus: 200statusText: "OK"type: 4url: null__proto__: HttpResponseBase
```

When I open developer tools I am able to see response headers but its not there in my intercept file.

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Date:Tue, 11 Dec 2018 13:16:54 GMT
Expires:0
Pragma:no-cache
t:eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJhZG1pbkBuZXRhcHAuY29tIiwic2NvcGVzIjpbeyJhdXRob3JpdHkiOiIxIn1dLCJpc3MiOiJodHRwOi8vY3JvLm5ldGFwcC5jb20iLCJpYXQ (I need to get this "t" value in my intercept file)
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff
X-Frame-Options:DENY
X-XSS-Protection:1; mode=block
```

Comment: look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968674/angular-6-get-response-headers-with-httpclient-issue/50969834#50969834 look at exposedHeaders and allowedHeaders

Comment: Thanks but In that case function is getting call with some url as an arg. but in my case I am not calling any such function..

Comment: i mean that if you want to exchange some custom headers you must enable them into backend