# Angular 7 HttpClient post response headers are empty

Tags: angular, spring-security, angular7, angular-httpclient

I am trying to perform login from Angular 7 with Spring security backend:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('username', username);
    formData.append('password', password);

    return this.http.post<UserInfo>(`${API_URL}/login`, formData, {observe: 'response'})
      .pipe(map(response => {

        const jwtToken = response.headers.get(AUTHORIZATION).replace('Bearer', '').trim();
        const userInfo = response.body;

        if (jwtToken && userInfo) {
          const user = new User(username, password, jwtToken, userInfo);
          localStorage.setItem(CURRENT_USER, JSON.stringify(user));
          this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
        }

        return response;
      }));
  }
```

But, response.headers is simply empty and contains no headers whatsoever. Postman and Chrome dev tools show many headers and even the one I need - Authorization. I have reviewed many SO questions and github issues, but they all say the same thing, which does not work for me - to simply list the header in CORS Access-Control-Expose-Headers, but I have done that and nothing changed. Here is a relevant Spring configuration:

```
@Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:4200");
        configuration.addExposedHeader("Authorization");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

At this point I am stuck and have no idea how to make Angular access those headers:

[image]

Comment: what is `AUTHORIZATION`? in `response.headers.get(AUTHORIZATION)`

Comment: It's simply a constant stored in a file where I keep all constants and enums: export const AUTHORIZATION = 'Authorization';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `authorization header`, which you can get by `response.headers.get("Authorization")`. Try:

```
const jwtToken = response.headers.get("Authorization").replace('Bearer', '').trim();
```

Comment: For some reason, when I replaced a constant with an actual inlined string, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

On server side you need to configure "Access-Control-Allow-Headers". Refer this post: [Angular 6 Get response headers with httpclient issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968674/angular-6-get-response-headers-with-httpclient-issue) .

For me this configuration did the trick:

```
@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addExposedHeader(
            "Authorization, x-xsrf-token, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, "
                    + "Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Custom-Filter-Header");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return source;
}
```

Comment: I already did that, I mention it in my original question. It does not work.

Comment: That is what I have configured:

Comment: I've added my configuration above. addExposedHeader contains "Access-Control-Allow-Headers".