# How to get response Header in Angular 8 for post request

Tags: angular

How to get response Header in Angular 8 for post request and store the jwt token in localstorage

```
login(req): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + '/login', req).pipe(
    map(res => {
      if (res) {
        this.loggedIn.next(true);

      }
      return res;
    })
  );
}
```

[image: response headers]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 6 Get response headers with httpclient issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968674/angular-6-get-response-headers-with-httpclient-issue)

Answer (score 0):

```
loadToken() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    this.authToken = token;
  }

createAuthHeader() {
    this.loadToken();
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set(
      'Authorization',
      `Bearer ${this.authToken}`
    );
    return { headers };
  }

login(formData) {
    return this.http.post(`${this.url}/login`, formData,this.createAuthHeader());
  }
```

you need to pass header as a third param inside post req.
refer this example.

Answer (score 0):

To see the response headers of your request, you need to use the [`observe: 'response'`](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) option in your request:

```
return this.http.post(this.apiUrl + '/login', req, { observe: 'response'}).pipe(
  map((response) => {
    const data = response.data; // the data returned from your request
    const keys = response.headers.keys(); // keys of the response headers
    const headers = keys.map((key) => response.headers.get(key)); // values of the response headers

    // So to get the token, you need to do
    const JWTtoken = response.header.get('JWT-TOKEN');

    // To store you do:
    localStorage.set('JWT-TOKEN', JWTtoken);

    return data;
  });
);
```

Comment: but i got null in JWT-Token

Comment: @akhilashok check the keys array, to see the correct key to get from `response.header.get()`. It's case sensitive

Comment: 0: "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
1: "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
2: "0"
3: "no-cache"

Comment: these are my keys array,you can check the image when i uploded yesterday there  is no keys for jwt-token

Comment: @akhilashok you need to expose the `JWT-TOKEN` header in your server backend. The how to, depends on the server technology you are using