# How can I capture all headers when using HttpClient - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, xmlhttprequest, httpclient

Using javascript XMLHttpRequest I can easily use the getAllResponseHeaders() method to get the headers

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
```

get a result similar to this:

```
accept-ranges: bytes
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-length: 4546
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
date: Mon, 18 May 2020 04:24:30 GMT
etag: W/"11c2-u8XhnlVk5uwUwaHTXsnarcbbBQw"
x-powered-by: Express
```

Now I want to use it in Angular, but I can't figure out how to get those values when I launch a request using HttpClient.

Comment: check this link it might be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50968674/angular-6-get-response-headers-with-httpclient-issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http-interceptor in angular. 
Interceptors are a way to do some work for every single HTTP request or response.

Here you can get header for both request and response for a http request

Please check the following link for example:

https://blog.angulartraining.com/http-interceptors-in-angular-61dcf80b6bdd

In the following part of interceptor(after response)

```
return next.handle(authReq).pipe(
  // We use the map operator to change the data from the response
  map(resp => {
     // Several HTTP events go through that Observable 
     // so we make sure that this is a HTTP response
     if (resp instanceof HttpResponse) {
        //extract your headers here
       let newHeaders = resp.headers;
    }
  })
);
```